# What is meant by 包容力見せてる here?

Tags: meaning, spoken-language

> 「やん、宇奈月ちゃんったら。彼氏くんの方が攻め攻めかと思ってたら、しっかり**包容力見せてる**じゃん」
>
> 「なんだかんだで、年下の男の子に好きにさせてあげてるって感じだったよね」

Context: A girl was talking to her boyfriend and these two girls were listening in on their conversation. After she came back inside they started talking to her.

In the above I'm a bit lost as to what 包容力見せてる means and who is the one doing it. Is it referring to her boyfriend or her?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the girl who is showing her 包容力 (to her boyfriend).

彼氏くんの方が攻め攻め implies the boyfriend was aggressive and taking initiative, and the girl was acting rather passively. But in reality, the girl was not that passive, but was intentionally letting him do as he likes (with her "broad-mindedness" ≒ 包容力).